# How do I import a certificate to the Certstore on remote systems when WinRM is disabled with powershell

Tags: powershell, certificate

How do I import a certificate with Powershell to the Certstore on remote systems when WinRM is disabled in the environment due to security. I have attempted a few work around and all have failed. Please be easy I'm a novice.

I have tried this as a work around and yes I know its the untrusted store.

```
$cert = getchilditem -path "SharePath.cer"
$server = Get-content ".\servers.txt"
$server | foreach { $cert | import-certificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:LocalMachine\Disallowed
```

Comment: `due to security` What?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 it's the age old "WinRM isn't safe" fallacy

Comment: Nothing in what you have shown in your code imports the certificate on a remote system. You pipe `$server` to a `ForEach` loop, but never reference `$_`. You may as well be piping random numbers, or breeds of cats to your `ForEach` loop.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "here's a thing I want to do in Windows, program it for me" is [not on-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350392/here-is-x-part-of-any-program-ever-how-do-i-get-change-this-in-powershell/).

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Thanks for providing useless information. I mentioned I was novice and I have no scripting/programming experience. Learning Powershell in a locked down environment is not fun as most resources references methods that use WinRM, which will not work. I don't know why you post if you not going assist people when they ask. How about providing feedback on why something will not  work instead of just bashing them.

Comment: @JWill I do assist people when they ask on-topic questions. When they ask off-topic questions, I closevote, as the site asks users to do. StackOverflow is not a general purpose forum, it asks users to vote to keep its content within certain guidelines. One of these, and a difficult line to walk, is the difference between "I have done 90% of X help me get unstuck" vs. "I want X but I can't do any of it, you design it, write it, and give it to me or teach me". I think the latter is outside the scope of the site, and saying "but I can't do it because I'm a novice" doesn't change that.

Comment: Note that you have a 13 paragraph answer because all it can do is throw possible ideas, because your problem is not narrowly scoped or clearly defined (wrt. what things you have available and can do), and your comment to it is "it doesn't work". That's why this is off-topic for the site - designing something which will fit within your infrastructure (which you haven't described) is going to require back and forth, quite a lot of it, and a huge answer. It's going to be overly specific to your environment. It's a question for any ordinary internet forum.

Comment: @Tessellating Thanks for the feedback the second time around. However, I did not expect you or anybody else to write it. I expected some to to just tell me what I did wrong. Like hey idiot you forgot "X". I didn't realize people only write questions on here if they know how to write their code already. I guess people only wright rhetorical questions on here. I now know.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying certificates to computers is probably best accomplished via [Group Policy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770315(v=ws.10).aspx) as it is a far more robust and easy to use process.

That being said if you cannot use Group Policy you may be able to use one of several other solutions depending on your target System's OS.

[Boe Prox wrote an Import-Certificate](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2014/11/18/certificate-to-a-store-using-powershell.aspx) function and explanation that uses .Net under the covers to allow imports on remote computers without WinRM or older than Windows 10. Using his solution you can do the following:

```
$File = "C:\temp\SomeRootCA.cer"    
$Computername = 'Server1','Server2','Client1','Client2'    
Import-Certificate -Certificate $File -StoreName Disallowed -StoreLocation LocalMachine -ComputerName $Computername
```

If you are on Windows 10 you can use the built in [Import-Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/import-certificate?view=win10-ps) but this only works for the local system. So you will need to wrap it with Invoke-Command (which requires WinRM) or you can fallback to [Invoke-WMIMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/invoke-wmimethod?view=powershell-5.1). It's  not nearly as friendly to use or work with output, but it will work. This is a working example of executing a function on a remote computer without WinRM. For complex commands you will want to use the -[EncodedCommand parameter of powershell.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help?view=powershell-5.1).

Copy cert to the remote system to avoid 2 hop issues

```
Copy-Item "C:\temp\SomeRootCa.cer" "\\Computer1\C$\temp\"
```

Encode the command we want to use

```
$encoded = [Convert]::ToBase64String(
               [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes(
                   {Import-Certificate -FilePath C:\temp\somerootca.cer -CertStoreLocation cert:\localmachine\disallowed}
               )
           )
```

Spawn a process on the remote computer

```
Invoke-WmiMethod -Class Win32_Process -Name Create -ArgumentList "powershell.exe -encodedcommand $encoded" -ComputerName Computer1
```

You will get output similar to the following on your computer

```
__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     :
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        :
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 2
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         :
__NAMESPACE      :
__PATH           :
ProcessId        : 8748
ReturnValue      : 0
PSComputerName   :
```

Note that the return value of 0 indicating success only indicates that powershell was spawned, not that the commands you executed were successful. If you want some logging you will need to bake it into the command you encode

EDIT: [Foreach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-5.1) and [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-5.1)

```
Get-Content C:\some\file\name\here.txt | Foreach-Object -begin {
    $encoded = [Convert]::ToBase64String(
               [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes(
                   {Import-Certificate -FilePath C:\temp\somerootca.cer -CertStoreLocation cert:\localmachine\disallowed}
               )
           )
} -process {
    if(Test-Connection $_ -quiet){
        Copy-Item "C:\temp\SomeRootCa.cer" "\\$_\C$\temp\"
        Invoke-WmiMethod -Class Win32_Process -Name Create -ArgumentList "powershell.exe -encodedcommand $encoded" -ComputerName $_
    }
}
```

Please do not copy/pasta this into a production environment. Read it and understand what is happening. Use the [ISE to debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/ise/how-to-debug-scripts-in-windows-powershell-ise?view=powershell-5.1) portions of the functions and piece it together bit by bit.

Comment: THanks for the feedback and understanding that I'm new to powershell and programming in general. The scripts you provided however is still not working. I'm not receiving any errors and the return is 0 showing that the script ran. However still no Certificate in the store. The Copy function is working fine and the cert is on the specified server.

Comment: Also forgot to mention. This scripts hard codes the server name into the script. I'm looking at updating hundards of servers. This is why I was attempted the get-content and running a for-each, even though I wasn't doing it correctly.

Comment: Just use `get-content C:\somefilewithservernames.txt` to pull in the server names and send it to a `foreach-object` command that wraps whichever set of commands you chose to use.